# Virtual and physical addresses after fork

Tags: c

What happens behind the scenes with the virtual address space of the child process after a fork?

I've been reading in other posts about it, but what some people said went against what others said, and it kind of messed up the idea I had in my head.

Take for example this code:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a = 5;

    dummy(&a);

    return 0;
}

void dummy(int * a){
    if(fork()==0){
        printf("%p",a);
        *a=10;
    }
    else{
       printf("%p",a);
       printf("%d\n",*a); //a is still 5
    }
}
```

Why is the value of `%p` the same after both printf, but when I change the value of `a` in the child it's not reflected on the parent. When `%p` is printed, it refers to the virtual address of the variable?

Are the virtual addresses of the child the same of the parent (before any changes to the heap are done),
or the new child process has it own virtual addresses, that point to the same physical addresses of the parent (as long as no change is made to the variables in the heap)?

I've read that when a change is done to a variable located on the child's heap, the physical memory is cloned and the virtual address now points to this newly cloned physical address (where the variable is now changed)—a process known as copy-on-write.

Comment: All addresses you ever see are virtual. Physical addresses are thoroughly hidden from your program. They are unimportant unless you are writing an OS kernel. The memory of the forked process is an exact copy of the memory of the parent process. This includes addresses of all things.

Comment: If you want to poke at actual physical addresses either play with an existing OS kernel or play with some MS-DOS real mode programs (since real mode doesn't support memory virtualization (with some minor caveats)), the adresses used there are actual physical memory adresses.

Comment: This could be interesting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58145/how-does-copy-on-write-in-fork-handle-multiple-fork

Answer (score 3):

> Why is the value of %p the same after both printf, but when I change the value of a in the child it's not reflected on the parent. When %p is printed, it refers to the virtual address of the variable?

Moving around the virtual addresses of objects would cause programs to crash. They store virtual addresses to objects in their variables. After a `fork`, both instances have virtual address space with the same layout.

> Are the virtual addresses of the child the same of the parent (before any changes to the heap are done), or the new child process has it own virtual addresses, that point to the same physical addresses of the parent (as long as no change is made to the variables in the heap)?

I don't understand how this is a meaningful difference.

> I've read that when a change is done to a variable located on the child's heap, the physical memory is cloned and the virtual address now points to this newly cloned physical address (where the variable is now changed)—a process known as copy-on-write.

That's correct. That avoids having to make two copies in physical memory of every single page the process that calls `fork` has mapped.

Comment: Re “I don't understand how this is a meaningful difference”: In the former, the child and parent both have virtual address 100 for some object `x`. In the latter, the child has address 4100, the parent has address 100, and both point to the same physical address. The former is correct, for pages not modified since the fork, subject to the operating system doing that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As I understand what he's saying, he understands that they are numerically the same. By "its own virtual addresses", I don't think he means its own numerical values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil what I was trying to say was the following. Lets suppose the parent process has the following virtual addresses: 100,200,300 and the address 100 is mapped to the physical address 800 (where a is stored). When fork is called, are the virtual addreses the same as the parent (100,200,300) ? And when trying to change the vaue of a, is the virtual address 100 of the child process now mapped to another physical address i.e. 900, which corresponds to a copy of the physical address 800 where the variable was stored but now allocates the newly changed value?

Comment: @FRANCISCOBERNAD You seem to have it backwards.  For example: `pid_t pid; pid_t *ptr = &pid; fork(); *ptr = getpid();`  If the virtual address of `pid` is `0x100` in the parent process before `fork()` is called, is has to be `0x100` in the child process also because the value in `ptr` in  both processes is not going to change across the fork.  COW means a new physical page is copied from the original and then mapped to the same virtual address.  There's no other way it could work because there's no way to be sure what the `0x100` value in the address space refers to.

Comment: (cont) Bits are just bits, and the value `0x100` in a process's address space could be an address or it could be a count of something.  How the process will interpret that value in the future is unknown to the virtual memory manager, so the virtual addresses of pages in the parent and child process must be the same to ensure references to objects in those page(s) remain valid.

Answer (score 2):

When fork is called, the virtual address space (as well as file descriptors) is copied into the new process. This means that for all intents and purposes the two processes are identical.

Now to ensure the two processes remain independent all physical memory is made read-only. When an attempt to write is made, a processor exception is raised. The kernel then pages in a new page and copies data from the original page. It then reruns the process and allows the write.

For this to work the processor must have a Memory Management Unit that maps physical memory to virtual space. This means that Unmodified Linux cannot run on Micro-controller units.